# How can I call all Cases using SOQL query to mass delete all my Case's?

Tags: soql, case, delete

This is my code to mass delete my Cases:

```
List<Case> caseList=[Select CaseNumber From Case];
for(Case cases : caseList);
delete caseList;
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be condensed to a one-liner:

```
delete [SELECT Id FROM Case];
```

Note that if you have more than 10,000 records in `Case`, it won't work, because the DML rows limit is 10,000. You would need to export the data using Data Loader and perform the deletion that way, write a batch class, or add a `LIMIT` clause:

```
delete [SELECT Id FROM Case LIMIT 10000];
```

and run it repeatedly until the Cases are gone.

---

This `for` loop does nothing at all:

```
for(Case cases : caseList);
```

The semicolon represents an empty loop body.

Answer (score 1):

If your cases count is not more then that 10000 then this query will work for you.

```
delete [SELECT Id FROM Case LIMIT 10000];
```

But in case you have large amount of cases like 20k or 1M or more then in that case you have to write batch apex and execute it from developer console.

You can count no. of case with this query.

```
  Integer i = [Select Count(id) From Case];
  System.debug('Total Cases count::'+i);
```

For Batch apex

```
global class OldDataDeleter implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

 global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator('Select ID from Case');
 }

 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Case> records){
    delete records;
 }

 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context){        
 }
}
```

Save this class and then go to developer console in Anonymous window write this code and then execute.

```
  Database.executeBatch(new OldDataDeleter());
```